# Disadvantages of using OpenGL for embedded linux

Tags: opengl, user-interface, embedded-linux

Now I'm facing a problem regarding plotting some curves in a Qt and Qwt application for embedded linux (see more details about the problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895261/slow-replot-of-a-qwt-graph-in-embedded-linux) link).

One of the proposed solutions was to use OpenGL together with QwtPlot, but my boss fears that OpenGL would ensure its graphical optimization with a higher processing cost, so essentially improving in one area to cause problem in another. I must say that this reasoning seems convincing.

Now I haven't checked how much exactly the improvements would be, neither I know how much extra processing OpenGL usage would take, but I came after this to do a more general question (whose answer may actually refute my boss' thesis): *what are the disadvantages of using OpenGL, particularly for a embedded linux situation?* I tried to find something on the web, but Google wouldn't help be with disadvantages apart from the issues related to the fight between OpenGL and DirectX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but my boss fears that OpenGL would ensure its graphical optimization with a higher processing cost,

Your boss is speculating without having actual knowledge on the subject. This is akin to premature optimization.

OpenGL is not a library, it's an API to access graphics systems and it has been deliberately designed to have very little overhead and do not provide anything beyond what GPUs actually can do. There are no higher level kinds of "objects" in OpenGL. All what OpenGL does is making the GPU draw points, lines or triangles in exactly the order and way, you tell it to.

> what are the disadvantages of using OpenGL, particularly for a embedded linux situation?

If your target embedded device has a OpenGL capable GPU: Zero. In fact using OpenGL will then greatly improve performance and reduce load on the CPU. More likely on an embedded system you'll have to deal with OpenGL-ES, though. In your other post you mention you're using a TI OMAP. Which one exactly? Because some of them come with PowerVR GPUs.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Since you asked, I'm using OMAP L138. You mentioned OpenGL-ES, but Wikipedia tells it's a 3D library when I only need 2D; wouldn't there be a more limited version?

Comment: @Momergil: 2D is just 3D with one component of the vectors kept 0. Also neither OpenGL nor OpenGL-ES are libraries (no matter what Wikipedia says). They are specified as APIs, and as such are system level modules that come with the operating system. And these days all GPUs are designed for "3D" operation, with only a handfull of special 2D functional units (like video decoding). To be honest, when we talk about "3D" GPU then we actually mean graphics processors that can cleverly work with 4-element vectors (for homogenous coordinates) that end up as 2D raster images in some framebuffer.

Comment: @Momergil: Now the OMAP L138 doesn't come with an integrated graphics processor, which means that programs have to fill the framebuffer with content themself. OpenGL is optimized for operating on a graphics processor; there are software implementations, but those are usually outperformed by special purpose drawing routines for the same result (however very likely any general purpose graphics library you'd write would be outperformed by highly optimized OpenGL software emulations). QwtPlot depends on the Qt drawing functions, which, in recent versions of Qt use OpenGL.

Comment: @Momergil: It boils down, that you're running on a device without dedicated graphics processor, however most likely the existing software drawing methods you're using already are very performant. You can try to implement your own drawing routines and see how well it works.

Comment: well, thank you very much for your reply, both the explanations as well as seeing the L138 situation! It helped a lot :)
And btw, my mistake: Wikipedia tells it's an API actually; it was me who didn't pay attention :)